# What's a good design for catching Errors/Exceptions with line inputs?

Tags: java

my code is to read lines from a .txt and parse those inputs.

inputs are in this form `<operation> <category> <name> <price> <quantity> <weight> <optional field1> <optional field2>`

Electronics have 2 option fields is it fragile (F/NF) and the state it's shipping to, groceries have 1 optional field perishable (P/NP). here's a few example of line inputs

`insert clothing shirt 20.50 1 1`

`insert electronics PS3 300 1 5.2 F NM`

`insert groceries cabbage 2.00 5 1 NP`

Im thinking of writing a `legalLine()` method to process the errors in inputs

```
class sampleClass{
          public static void isLegalLine(String lineInput){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(lineInput);
    String operation = null;
    String category = null;
    String name = null;
    float price = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    float weight = 0;
    String opt1 = null;
    String opt2 = null;
    try{
        operation = s.next(); 
        category = s.next();
        name = s.next();
        price = Float.parseFloat(s.next());
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
        weight = Float.parseFloat(s.next());
        if (!operation.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")
                && !operation.equalsIgnoreCase("search")
                && !operation.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")
                && !operation.equalsIgnoreCase("update")
                && !operation.equalsIgnoreCase("print")) {
            System.out.println("invalid operation");
        }
        // more validations for variables category, name, price, quantity, weight goes here
        if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("electronics")){
            try{
                opt1 = s.next();
                opt1 = s.next();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }else if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("groceries")){
            opt1 = s.next();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        //general catch for now
        e.getMessage();
    }
}


          public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
               FileReader freader = new FileReader(args[0]);
               BufferedReader bfrReader = new BufferedReader(freader);
               isLegalLine(bfrReader.readLine());


                //program does calculation for total price of input
}
```

you see... I've gone through all the trouble setting each token to its respective variables in the `isLegalLine()`, how can I pass those information back to the `main()`? and is this a good design for processing input line errors?

Comment: I would expect `isLegalLine` method to return a boolean (not void).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will need to process them as well, a good solution I see is this:

Create a Product class with three subclasses: clothing, electronics, and groceries

Then make your function

```
public static Product isLegalLine(String lineInput)
```

return the Product after parsing the line.

Comment: this seems like a good solution. Does each Product subclass would have its own `isLegalLine()` method?

Comment: I was thinking it would just be a container with whatever you cared about: a field for each category, name, price, quantity, weight, and each Product subclass would have its own fields to represent the extra information. isLegalLine() has really now become parseLine(). Each Product could have its own implementation of whatever you plan to do in main() with it.

Comment: uhm... im still not totally sure how to implement this... :(

Comment: Well, one thing which could help is if you answered: what do you do with the product once you understand what it is?

Comment: im going to perform some calculations on it, say `(20*(weight))*quantity` for standard products, Sales tax rate is 10% for clothing and electronics, Premium shipping incurs an additional charge of 20% for perishable products. so, like you said, it makes sense to create 3 subclasses of Product(so each class can use it's `calculateTotal()`).. but im not sure how to deal with `isLegalLine()` method, how to pass the information...

Comment: Okay, so as above: the isLegalLine() is in the sampleClass returning a Product to main().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19964/discussion-between-user133466-and-nair-ashvin)

Answer (score 1):

I think, it will be better to read your file line by line. Then you'll apply regular expression to each line and thus you'll get your parameters - either mandatory and optional.

Regular expression will be something like that:

```
([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*([\w\d\.]*)\s*
```

Every expression in brackets will correspond to a single parameter.
The example of code is:

```
String pattern = "([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*([\\w\\d\\.]*)\\s*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
for(String str : strings) {
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  m.find();
  if(m.matches()) {
     String operation = m.group(1);
     String category = m.group(2);
     ...
     float weight = Float.parseFloat(m.group(6));
     String opt1 = m.group(7);
     String opt2 = m.group(8);
  }
}
```

Then you just check whether optional parameters are present (or aren't present) for an operation and generate errors if necessary.
You can pass any information back to main(...) method by returning a value. Return value can be anything you want.